# Is $\mathbb{R}^1$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My intuition tells me it is.

But in terms of vectors, the span of a vector with only one component (a vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$) is not said to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What is the definition of a linear subspace?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, you do have subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{[r,0]\mid r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is one in particular from the isomorphism $r\mapsto [r,0]$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Technically**, the answer is no, because $\mathbb{R}^1$ is *not a subset of* $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\mathbb{R}^1$ consists of real numbers, whereas $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of ordered pairs of real numbers; therefore $\mathbb{R}^1$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**However**, there are many ways one can "put a copy of $\mathbb{R}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$", and *depending on how this is done*, the result may or may not be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Look at the [definition of a subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace), and consider that 
$$S=\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^1\}$$
is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because

- the zero vector, $(0,0)\in S$
- for any two $(a,0),(b,0)\in S$, we have that $(a,0)+(b,0)=(a+b,0)\in S$
- for any $(a,0)\in S$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $c(a,0)=(ca,0)\in S$

while

$$T=\{(x,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^1\}$$

completely fails to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - every condition is false:

- the zero vector, $(0,0)\notin T$
- for any two $(a,1),(b,1)\in T$, we **don't** have that $(a,1)+(b,1)=(a+b,2)\in T$
- for any $(a,1)\in T$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$, we **don't** have that $c(a,1)=(ca,c)\in T$ (unless $c=1$)

Generally, you should note that it is entirely possible for a subspace of a vector space $V$ to have smaller dimension than $V$; for example, for any vector space $V$, the subset consisting of only the zero element is always a subspace, and it has dimension 0.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the edit, Henning :)

Comment: hmm, ok that makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: You ain't getting a better answer then that. Good job,guys!

Comment: Not to mention that there are maps $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ whose image is not even an affine subspace.